# Transparent TCustomControl?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, custom-component

I need to create transparent component inheriting from TCustomControl.. so it is custom painted, yet is container for other components.

Can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: How is what you're asking for different from a TPanel without a border that has the color of its parent? A little more detail? Are you asking about "transparent on aero glass", or mere inheritance of parent color color, or parent control texture?

Comment: by "transparent" I mean it doesn't cover the background. So it behaves like TLabel with transparency enabled, yet it is able to host other controls.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Inherit from [`TCustomTransparentControl`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TCustomTransparentControl.html) and include [`csAcceptsControls`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControlStyle.html) control style at creation.

Comment: +1 - I didn't know that class existed.  When was it introduced?  If it's been there as long as CB6 (~2001 or Delphi 7 timeframe) I'll be a sad panda.  (I wrote a TWinControl descendant class to do this myself, and it was surprisingly tricky.)

Comment: @David - No need to be sad, it appears to have been introduced with [Delphi 2006](http://delphi.about.com/od/productreviews/ss/delphi2006first_7.htm).

Comment: Seemed too good to be true... Replaced my `TCustomControl` with `TCustomTransparentControl`, compiled, and somehow it does not respond to the mouse at all now... More work to do.

Comment: @Jerry - Did you set 'interceptmouse'?

Comment: Yup, figured that out shortly after my comment. Now other issues :-(